# Buscar valores em um objeto

Tags: javascript, json, array

Estou tentando acessar propriedades de um objeto, um dicionário.

Contudo as referencias são em formato `{String}` e sua concatenação através de ponto (**.**) e estou utilizando `split()` para quebrar esta `{String}` em uma matriz... más isto acaba por me fazer utilizar vários `if|else` na função de pesquisa.

```
let base = {} // o dicionário
let str = 'indice.subindice.chave' // a referencia
//
let m = str.split('.') // a matriz de consulta
//
return base[m[0]][m[1]][m[2]][m[3]]
```

Basicamente todos os valores deste dicionário são `{String}` más se a referencia for maior que o estipulado na função de busca acaba retornando um `{Object}`.

Há alguma maneira mais limpa e concisa de buscar estes valores pela referencia?

**exemplo**:

```js
let base = {
    misc: {
       first: 'look',
       level: {
          move: 'handler'
       }
    },
    words: {
       page: {
          index: {
             nav: 'rule',
             aside: {
                bottom: 'awesome'
             }
          }
       }
    }
}

function getWord(list) {
    //
    try {
        let array = list.split('.');
        if ( Array.isArray(array) && array.length > 0 ) {
            if ( array[3] ) {
                return base[array[0]][array[1]][array[2]][array[3]];
            } else if ( array[2] ) {
               return base[array[0]][array[1]][array[2]];
            } else {
               return base[array[0]][array[1]];
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

$('.btn ').on('click', function(evt) {
    let word = $(this).attr('data')
    console.log(getWord(word))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn" data="misc.first">nível 1</button>

<button class="btn" data="misc.level.move">nível 2</button>

<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.nav">nível 3</button>

<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.aside.bottom">nível 4</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, utilizando a função [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const base = {
    misc: {
       first: 'look',
       level: {
          move: 'handler'
       }
    },
    words: {
       page: {
          index: {
             nav: 'rule',
             aside: {
                bottom: 'awesome'
             }
          }
       }
    }
}

$('.btn ').on('click', function(evt) {
    const word = $(this).attr('data');
    console.log(getWord(word));
})

function getWord(list) {
    return list.split('.').reduce((o,i) => o[i], base);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data="misc.first">nível 1</button>
<button class="btn" data="misc.level.move">nível 2</button>
<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.nav">nível 3</button>
<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.aside.bottom">nível 4</button>
```

Comment: Isso realmente foi sucinto... obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Podes utilizar o método [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), mas creio que não seja a melhor opção.

```js
let base = {
    misc: {
       first: 'look',
       level: {
          move: 'handler'
       }
    },
    words: {
       page: {
          index: {
             nav: 'rule',
             aside: {
                bottom: 'awesome'
             }
          }
       }
    }
}

const get_word = (list) => {
  let test = eval(`base.${list}`);
  return (test) ? test : false;
};


$('.btn ').on('click', function(evt) {
    let word = $(this).attr('data')
    console.log(get_word(word))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data="misc.first">nível 1</button>
<button class="btn" data="misc.level.move">nível 2</button>
<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.nav">nível 3</button>
<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.aside.bottom">nível 4</button>
<button class="btn" data="words.page.index.aside.bottom.nao_existe">nível 5</button>
```

#### Referência

- [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Interessante não sabia poder fazer isto com `eval()` más não posso aplicar devido a um **CSP** restritivo. Mesmo assim agradeço a resposta.